# Should it be "mid 80s" or "mid-80s"?

Tags: hyphenation, numbers, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

When discussing temperatures or decades, should it be hyphenated?
I understood that two-word adjectives need to be hyphenated, but why does MS Word think this should be, too?

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing your MS Word sentence--are you confused why it *does* follow the rule that things should be hyphenated?

Comment: @simchona: I think the confusion is that "mid" is a word and "80s" is not a word (at least I assume it is not, according to the poster, or why post this question) but MS Word hyphenates it as if "mid" and "80s" were two word.

Comment: What sentence is this flagged as an error in? I can't duplicate it with some simple examples in Word, but I'm not sure if I've turned on grammar checking correctly. @simchona, The problem is that this phrase is not necessarily an adjective. You would say "In the mid 80s" for example.

Comment: Examples of sentences: 1) "The temperature yesterday was in the mid 80s." 2) "He was born sometime during the mid 80s." Concerning MS Word, I thought "mid 80s" is correct but it wanted to change it to "mid-80s" and I disagree. Thanks everyone

Comment: Does it just do it with "mid", or also high/low/early/late? Part of the problem may be that "mid" is perceived as somehow not being a real word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should it be "mid 80s" or "mid-80s"?

Yes.

My *American Heritage Dictionary* has entries for the adjective 'mid' and the prefix 'mid-'.

Modifying the noun *80s* with the adjective *mid* would be written as *mid 80s*.

But creating word by appending the noun *80s* to the prefix *mid* would be written as *mid-80s*.

So, it depends on which form of *mid* you use.

Please note that if there is a standard dictionary for the project you are working on, you must ensure that there is an entry for the adjective *mid*, not just the prefix. If no such entry exists, you're stuck with the prefix *mid*, which means you're also stuck with the hyphen.

Comment: Yes, as I just posted above, I am using "mid" as an adjective to modify "80s." Thus it makes the most sense to me to have it without the hyphen. But now I understand that MS Word thinks I was creating a two-word adjective like "mid-80s music" or "mid-80s temperature." Thanks for everyone's comments.

Comment: This has just resurfaced. Could you please highlight the section verbatim, link and attribute?

Answer (score 2):

This is really a kind of corner case where there's probably no consensually accepted solution used and preferred by the majority of speakers.

Just either:

- if you have no editor, use whichever you think looks clearest to read and don't worry about it too much;
- if you have an editor, use whichever your editor tells you to use (or let them worry about it).

Answer (score 0):

I would normally go for the non-hyphenated case.

NB "mid '80s" is more correct for decades because it is a contraction of "mid 1980s" (presumably).

Comment: Yeah, but that also just depends on your preference for how you use apostrophes. Would you write 'phone, for example?

Comment: "More correct" does not mean I'd always (or even prefer to) use it. But, yes, 'phone is still a contraction of telephone.

Comment: Mmmm OK, why exactly do you consider it "more correct", then? Unless you think that (a) God stipulates this kind of thing, or (b) the use of the apostrophe in a particular place is intrinsically tied to some phenomenon of nature, then really what you're left with is a matter of preference. Maybe in some cases it's a collective preference, but it's still a preference!

Comment: I would've thought the use of apostrophes in contractions was pretty clear, and I would agree that there certainly should be one in **'80s**. The example **'phone** is different - you're talking about the usage and spelling of a single word that changes over time, such as **Halloween**. Indicating a contraction such as **'80s** is a different kettle of fish.

Comment: I suppose my "more correct" means "more formal": if you're writing in a context where you'd expect to have nits picked, using __'phone__ (or probably the full word __telephone__) is less likely to be questioned than just __phone__. (In fact I see both the same as @Snubian, but __'80s__ is not as "changed" as __'phone__.)