# Period after "fax"

Tags: periods

What are the rules for putting a full stop after a fax abbreviation?
Sometimes I see:

Tel.: xxx-xxx-xxx
Fax.: xxx-xxx-xxx

Is "fax" here an abbreviation?

Comment: Sloppy people are sloppy...... I see periods in a great many places where none belong........

Comment: @ЯegDwight And, commas, as well!

Comment: Why does everyone keep editing to add the extra x into the question? Phone numbers *in the US and Canada* are of the form xxx-xxx-xxxx, but every country has different numbering plans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need for a period. *Fax* is no longer an abbreviation, but a word in its own right.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with both Alok and Barrie England in part, but suggest that the term **fax** was never an abbreviation requiring a period (at least in US), but a short form term.

Consider *doctor*. The abbreviation in US is Dr. (with a period). But there is a short form, somewhat informal, of *doc*, or more frequently, *Doc* without a period.

Similarly, the titles of certain religious figures are Brother and Sister. The abbreviations are respectively *Br.* and *Sr.*  However, the short form for those terms are *Bro* and *Sis* (although such short forms would rarely be used in addressing those religious types).

The term *telephone* also illustrates the point. The accepted abbreviation is *tel.* or *Tel.*, but there is a short form, *phone* that never takes a period.

While I have not done any analysis, a brief rumination leads me to the view that abbreviations almost always consist of letters that exist within the word that they represent. Obviously, there is no **x** in *facsimile*.

Comment: Re phone, note the conversation in the comments [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/41013/3612).

Comment: @MarkHurd Nice point. I think we come to these short forms in a number of ways, and there are often intermediate forms, spellings or punctuations.

Comment: Yeah, I think if there had been an abbreviation, it would have been *fac* or *facs* (with trailing period in the U.S.).  Note that *sox* (as in American baseball's Boston Red Sox and Chicago White Sox) is just a (slightly!) shorter word for *socks* and of course never takes a period.

Answer (score 6):

'Fax' is an abbreviation of 'facsimile'; though the full form is far more uncommon than say 'Telephone'